# Hide blocks of a model for estheticism in Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, show-hide

I have a model which looks like this :

[image: model]

And i would like to know if there is a show/hide tool to select all non colored blocks and hide them like this :

[image: after hiding]

And then be able to show them again.

Thanks !

Comment: No, the point of a graphical programming language is that you can see what's happening, your second screenshot shows no outputs, how would you know that your coloured blocks actually output anything? I would just create a subsystem for all of the blocks which you want to tidy up.

Comment: "What's happening" it's just for me for programming and debugging. When the user will simulate the model he just want to know what is red/orange/green. That's why i just want to show him coloured block so he is not lost with all this future logical operator blocks.

Comment: You're using the *colour* as an output? This is... unconventional. There are more suitable ways to show outputs. This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because it seems like you're trying to create a user interface with a Simulink model.

Comment: @Wolfie The model i showed is just a part. The full model is a simple subsystem(Red Green or Orange) then inside the subsystem are the model i show in the post and then in each subsystem of the model there is the same thing but with Variable (True or False) at the lower part. And so the user just want by changing the value of the variables see the impact in the full model not how it works. He just want to know if he change one variable to True for example which equipment (which are subsystem in the post model) become red or orange. I don't know if i'm enough clear?

Comment: So yes my model is half an UI half an equation process.